# Add pathPrefix to static image assets in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to get my static images that get put it in the static folder on build to have a pathPrefix that I set up in the gatsby config. Currently the images on build have a path of /static/image.jpg and I want to add the prefix of /lp/ so it would be /lp/static/image.jpg. Here is the code I am using below:

```
// Page Template //
<Img fluid={file.childImageSharp.fluid} />

export const query = graphql`
  file(relativePath: { eq: "image.jpg" }) {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 1600) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
  }
`;

// gatsby-config.js //
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: '/lp/',
  plugins : [
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
  ]
};
```

My folder structure is like:

```
public
  --index.html
  --static
    --image.jpg
  --page-data
src
--components
  --images
    --image.jpg
  --containers
  --modules
  --templates
    --PageTemplate.js
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/static-folder/) you have to put the static folder in the `root` of your project. So your structure would be like:

```
static
  --staticImage.jpg
public
  --index.html
  --page-data
src
--components
  --images
    --image.jpg
  --containers
  --modules
  --templates
    --PageTemplate.js
```

with this structure your static image would go to the root of your public folder, so you can just use it like: `"/staticImage.jpg"`

If you want to add a subfolder you can try put the folder under `static` so it could be like

```
static
  --subfolder
    --subImage.jpg
```

Probably this will appear on your public directory like `public/subfolder/subimage.jpg` so you can use it as `"/subfolder/subimage.jpg"`

Comment: Hey Felipe, thanks for the answer. I updated to the structure you suggested and the image path on build is still coming from the static folder and not the static/subfolder. I am looking through the documentation and seeing if I can see anything else. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I think it is something more to do with our site being hosted elsewhere and needing a pathPrefix added. This documentation here seems like it contains the fix. https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/path-prefix/#add-to-gatsby-configjs.

Comment: Thanks for your help Felipe. What you said and the documentation helped.